# Uipath how to add data from different excel sheets

Tags: uipath

E.g I have 3 sheets containing different values, let's say 3 in sheet 1, 5 in sheet2, 9 in sheet3, how do I add them together using uipath

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you have and what you need. I assume that those 3, 5, and 9 rows are everything in those sheets and nothing else. This is pretty simple. Here are the steps:

1. Create 3 `Excel Application scopes`
2. For each scope add:

   [image]

   1. Add a `Read Range`
   2. Create a new global variable called `dt1` (in the others `dt2` and `dt3`)
   3. Just `Write Range` into the `dataTable`
3. Finally, merge all 3 `dataTables` into one, do that with a `Merge DataTable`
   [image]

### Sheet number unknown

In case the number of sheets of your workbook(s) is/are unknown, simply use `GetSheets` which comes out of the box. The idea is as follows:

Excel Application Scope -> GetSheets -> Use Read Range activity and pass item under sheet name and store output in DataTable -> Use Merge DataTable activity to merge all sheets data and pass output of Read Range activity.

[image: get unknown number of sheets]

Comment: Added that image. It depends on what you need. Just do a mix of Read, Merge or Write at the end.

Comment: Nonono, just use the ```Read Range``` with the ```""``` and you read the whole sheet. Did you even try it? Works great. And that you simply do on all the sheets. Done.

Comment: Not sure what the benefit would be then. But sure you can also write Code if you want. There you are free to do whatever you need.

Comment: Than update your question. It is really unclear what you need. It sounds like merging a dt. But it could also be a simple addition of values. Not sure. So if you want proper answer you need to write proper questions. For the next time.